# Simplifying $\sum_{k=1}^{\log_{2}{n}}\log_{3}{\frac{n}{2^k}}$ in two ways gives different results

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms

I want to calculate the result of
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_{2}{n}}\log_{3}{\frac{n}{2^k}}$$ I used two below approaches. Both approaches are based on $\log A + \log B = \log (A \times B)$ and $\sum\limits_1^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ rules:

- $$
  \begin{align}
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_{2}{n}}\log_{3}{\frac{n}{2^k}} &= \log_{3}{\frac{n^{\log_{2}n}}{2^{1+2+...+\log_{2}{n}}}} \tag1\\
  &= \log_{3}{\frac{n^{\log_{2}n}}{2^{(\log_{2}n) (\log_{2}{n}\ +\ 1)}}} \tag2\\
  &= \log_{3}{(\frac{n}{2^{(\log_{2}{n})\ +\ 1}})^{{\log_{2}n}}} \tag3\\
  &= ({\log_{2}n})\times \log_{3}{(\frac{n}{2^{(\log_{2}{n})\ +\ 1}})} \tag4 \\
  &=  ({\log_{2}n})\times \log_{3}{(\frac{n}{2n})} \tag5\\
  &= ({\log_{2}n})\times \log_{3}{(\frac{1}{2})} \tag6
  \end{align}$$
- In this approach I use `Change of variables`: Get $m=\log_2 n$. So $$\begin{align}
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_{2}{n}}\log_{3}{\frac{n}{2^k}} &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\log_{3}{\frac{2^m}{2^k}} \tag7 \\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\log_{3}{2^{m-k}} \tag8 \\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}(m-k)\log_{3}{2} \tag9 \\
  &= (m^2 - \frac{m(m+1)}{2})\log_{3}{2} \tag{10} \\
  &= (\frac{m^2 - m}{2})\log_{3}{2} \tag{11}
  \end{align}$$ By substituting $\log_2 n$ instead of $m$, we will have: $$
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_{2}{n}}\log_{3}{\frac{n}{2^k}} = (\frac{{(\log_2 n)}^2 - {\log_2 n}}{2})\log_{3}{2} \tag{12}$$

As you can see the result of first approach is negative, so it must be wrong and the second approach must be true; but what is wrong in the first approach?

Comment: The summation, (1), evaluates to $\frac{(\log_{2}(n) - 1) \, \log(n)}{2 \, \log(3)}. $

Comment: A way to find your mistake yourself:  Substitute a value (say $n=4$) in each of the steps (1) to (6) to find where the error is.

Comment: The sum $1+2+\cdots+\log_{2}(n)=\dfrac{\log_{2}(n)\left(\log_{2}(n)+1\right)}{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. That was a mistake caused by carelessly.